# Reading double values in "Scanf" statement

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I wrote a program for finding a root of a fifth degree polynomial, in a range that the user decides as an input. 
for example:

**Please enter the coefficients of the polynomial:
-64 0 0 0 0 2**

**Please enter the range:**

**4 -5.7**

**Invalid range! Please enter the range:**

**2 3.5**

**The polynomial has a root: x=2.**

My problem is in when I enter for example the range **10.4 10.2" the program can't compare between two values and decide that its an invalid range.  For integers it works.

How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ZERO 0.00001

int main()
{
    double a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,end_of_range,beginning_of_range;
    int x,root;

    printf("Please enter the coefficients of the polynomial:\n");

    scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &a_0, &a_1, &a_2, &a_3, &a_4, &a_5);

    printf("Please enter the range:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &beginning_of_range, &end_of_range);
    while (beginning_of_range >= end_of_range)
    {
        printf("Invalid range! Please enter the range:\n");
        scanf("%lf%lf", &beginning_of_range, &end_of_range);
    }    
    x = beginning_of_range;    
    while (x <= end_of_range)
    {    
        if ((a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x*x + a_3*x*x*x + a_4*x*x*x*x + a_5*x*x*x*x*x >= -ZERO) 
         && (a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x*x + a_3*x*x*x + a_4*x*x*x*x + a_5*x*x*x*x*x <= ZERO))
        {
            root = x;
            printf("The polynomial has the root x=%d.", root);
            break;
        }

        x++;

        if( x > end_of_range)
        {
            printf("Could not find a root.");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I want the roots to be only Integers! that's why I declared `x` as an `int`.

And something strange is happening, when I enter the range [10.4, 10.3] it just wait for about 1 minute and then prints "Could not find a root", although it must print invalid range.

Comment: I think you just need to make `x` a `double` as well?

Comment: @DigitalNinja I declared x as an int because In want Integer roots only.

Comment: Okay, but when you make this `x = beginning_of_range;` assignment your beginning range is a floating point value. Like R Sahu said, what happens when root isn't an integer? You want to round it to a whole number?

Comment: the assignment just meant to deal with integer roots. other cases are ignored. I know its not perfect program, but apparently they want to teach us something from this, dealing with float numbers.

Comment: something strange happens, when I enter the range [10.4, 10.3] it just wait for about 1 minute and then prints "Could not find a root", although it must print invalid range.

Comment: I just ran your code posted and it prints the invalid range message when entering those two values...

Comment: I opened a new page on my Compiler and run it again at it worked :) apparently I've been working for many hours on it that the compiler just stopped responding :) thanks though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [A code for finding one root of fifth degree polynomial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398979/a-code-for-finding-one-root-of-fifth-degree-polynomial)

Answer (score 0):

Things to change:

1. Change the type of `x`. Instead of

   ```
   int x;
   ```

use

```
    double x;
```

2. Declare `root` as a variable.

   ```
   double root;
   ```
3. Fix the format used to print `root`. Instead of

   ```
   printf("The polynomial has the root x=%d.", root);
   ```

use

```
    printf("The polynomial has the root x=%lf.\n", root);
```

Comment: I added a note that I want the roots to be integers, does these changes will work for that cause?

Comment: @F1sargyan You can easily truncate a floating point number to an integer but how do you want to deal with the cases where the root is not an integer?

Comment: I will just ignore them, It just what the task is requiring.

Comment: @F1sargyan, in that case, you should use `std::round` to get the closest integer. If the difference between that and the root is larger than a tolerance, ignore the root. Otherwise, accept the root.

Answer (score 0):

Make `x` a `double`, but let it only take on integer values.

```
// x = beginning_of_range;
x = ceil(beginning_of_range);

// while (x <= end_of_range)
while (x <= floor(end_of_range))

  // x++
  x += 1.0;
```

This approach will have trouble when `|x|` is large (about `1/DBL_EPSILON`) as `x += 1.0;` may not result in a incremented `x`.

---

BTW:

```
double y = ((((a_5*x + a_4)*x + a_3)*x + a_2)*x + a_1)*x + a_0; 
// is numerically more stable (and likely faster) than 
y = (a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x*x + a_3*x*x*x + a_4*x*x*x*x + a_5*x*x*x*x*x;
```

Minor: Suggest removing `=` in range test. A range of [1 1] looks legitimate to me.

```
// while (beginning_of_range >= end_of_range)
while (beginning_of_range > end_of_range)
```